# Jquery - Hide text toggled

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide

in `http://jsbin.com/uveqad/1/edit` .
I want to do this

```
1. i click toggle1 => then show text1
2. next i click toggle2 : show text2
```

in this case i want : in step number 2, text2 which is showed, replace text1 before. simply, after i click toggle2, text will be printed just text2 which printed in text1 position.

Can you help this?
Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you need to hide the displayed `div`s before showing a new `div`, in this case with the given html markup, we will hide all `div`s whose id starts with `p`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bt1").click(function(){
    $('div[id^="p"]:visible').not("#p1").slideUp()
    $("#p1").slideToggle();
  });
  $("#bt2").click(function(){
    $('div[id^="p"]:visible').not("#p2").slideUp()
    $("#p2").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Demo: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uveqad/4/edit)